# Highcharts: Too many datapoints in scatter - only circles get rendered

Tags: javascript, boost, highcharts, scatter-plot

I have a Highchart with a scatterplot.
It seems, that when there are too many datapoints in the plot, all the shapes become circles while the legend shows different shapes. When I show less Data, the shapes are all correct.

Solution:

the "problem" is related to the boost module.
when a series exceeds the default value of 5000 datapoints, it renderes only circles instead of the intended shape.
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

Boost can be disabled by changing boost.enabled to false.
it is also possible to change series.boostThreshold to 0 to deacivate it or a higher value.
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.boostThreshold

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

the "problem" is related to the boost module. when a series exceeds the default value of 5000 datapoints, it renderes only circles instead of the intended shape. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

Boost can be disabled by changing boost.enabled to false. it is also possible to change series.boostThreshold to 0 to deacivate it or a higher value. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.boostThreshold